# Animations not playing on load or on click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Working on a  tip calculator with an animation on an h1 tag and a slideDown and slideUp on click on the h2 tags. Problem is, none of the animations are playing and the click event isn't working either.
Here is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tip Calculator</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="midtermcss.css">
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="animationJS.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="faqs">
        <h1>Tip facts</h1>
        <h2>Things to know before you tip</h2>
        <div>
            <p>Tips Account for 44 Billion dollars of the Food Industry</p>
            
            <p>7 States require servers to be paid minimum wage like everyone else</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Minnessota</li>
                    <li>Montana</li>
                    <li>Washington</li>
                    <li>Oregon</li>
                    <li>California</li>
                    <li>Nevada</li>
                    <li>Alaska</li>
                </ul>
            <p>Current Federal minimum tipped wage is $2.13 per hour can you live on that?</p>
            <p>Charging with Credit/Debit cards tends to reduce the average tip</p>
        </div>      
    </section>

    <section id="js">
    <h1 id="heading">Tip Calculator</h1>
        <label for="billAmount">Total Amount Of Bill:</label>
        <input type="text" id="billAmount"><br>
        
        <label for="percentTip">Percent To Tip:</label>
        <input type="text" id="percentTip"><br>
        
        <label for="amountPeople">How Many People?:</label>
        <input type="text" id="amountPeople"><br>
        
        <label for="totalTip">Tip Total:</label>
        <input type="text" id="totalTip"><br>
        
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input  type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate"><br>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // runs when an h2 heading is clicked
    $("#faqs h2").toggle(
        function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("minus");
            $(this).next().slideDown(1000, "easeOutBounce");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("minus");
            $(this).next().slideUp(1000, "easeInBounce");
        }
    );

    $("#faqs h1").animate({
        fontSize: "400%",
        opacity: 1,
        left: "+=375"
    }, 1000, "easeInExpo")
        .animate({
        fontSize: "175%",
        left: "-=200"
    }, 1000, "easeOutExpo");

    $("#faqs h1").click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            fontSize: "400%",
            opacity: 1,
            left: "+=375"
        }, 2000, "easeInExpo")
            .animate({
            fontSize: "175%",
            left: 0
        }, 1000, "easeOutExpo");
    });

});


var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
var calculateClick = function() {
    var billAmount = parseFloat($("billAmount").value);
    var percentTip = parseFloat($("percentTip").value);
    var amountPeople = parseInt($("amountPeople").value);

    if (isNaN(billAmount) || billAmount <= 0) {
        alert("Your bill can't be 0 or less.");
    } else if (isNaN(percentTip) || percentTip <= 0) {
        alert("The percentage should be a whole number.");
    } else if (isNaN(amountPeople) || amountPeople <= 0) {
        alert("You are 1 person never count yourself as less.");
    } else {
        var total = billAmount * (percentTip / 100) / amountPeople;
        $("totalTip").value = total.toFixed(2);
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    $("calculate").onclick = calculateClick;
    $("billAmount").focus();
}
```

Last but not least the CSS file since the open and minus classes are listed in there

```
        * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
section {
    padding: 0 1em .5em;
}
section.js {
    padding: 0 1em .5em;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: .5em 0;
}
label {
    float: left;
    width: 10em;
    text-align: right;
}
input {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
#faqs h1 { 
    position: relative;
    left: -168px;
    font-size: 125%;
    color: blue;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 120%;
    padding: .25em 0 .25em 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(images/plus.png) no-repeat left center;
}
h2.minus {
    background: url(images/minus.png) no-repeat left center;
}
div.open {
    display: block;
}
ul {
    padding-left: 45px;
}
li {
    padding-bottom: .25em;
}
p {
    padding-bottom: .25em;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

I can't figure out for the life of me why the animations work in a separate test file but when I use them now in my tip calculator they don't. I'm using [Murach's JavaScript and jQuery book](https://www.murach.com/shop/murach-s-javascript-and-jquery-4th-edition-detail) but this section has been terribly hard to understand.

Comment: It is odd to me that you include jQuery but then overwrite the `$` selector function for a custom getById function. Why is that?

Comment: It's how my teacher showed me how to fix the tip calculator before and it worked

Comment: You include jQuery `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>` and then further down in your code you redefine the shorthand jQuery function with `var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}` but it doesn't seem like you do in some special small scope. It seems to be in the global context.

Comment: It's how my teacher showed me how to fix the tip calculator before and it worked. But that was weeks ago. You think that could be the issue with the animations?

Comment: I would image so. Since that is defined outside document.ready that may execute before document.ready which completely overwrites jquery and all its animation functionality.

Comment: I removed the return document.getElementById(id); and then the tip calcculator stops working and the animations still don't work.

Comment: Look at the answer I posted and the fiddle. Is the fiddle working as you imagine it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you include jQuery but later on in the global scope you redefine the `$`:

```
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/u0von3g7/

All I did was change the variable name holding that function and replace it in the areas you were using it. Specifically:

```
var getById = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
var calculateClick = function() {
    var billAmount = parseFloat(getById("billAmount").value);
    var percentTip = parseFloat(getById("percentTip").value);
    var amountPeople = parseInt(getById("amountPeople").value);

    if (isNaN(billAmount) || billAmount <= 0) {
        alert("Your bill can't be 0 or less.");
    } else if (isNaN(percentTip) || percentTip <= 0) {
        alert("The percentage should be a whole number.");
    } else if (isNaN(amountPeople) || amountPeople <= 0) {
        alert("You are 1 person never count yourself as less.");
    } else {
        var total = billAmount * (percentTip / 100) / amountPeople;
        getById("totalTip").value = total.toFixed(2);
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    getById("calculate").onclick = calculateClick;
    getById("billAmount").focus();
}
```

$ is just shorthand for jQuery. When you include jQuery it creates two functions for you that both do the same thing. `jQuery` and `$`. If you set $ equal to something else you have effectively overwritten jQuery library included in your page and it will no longer operate as you would expect. All jQuery functionality begins with using $ or jQuery function. Once that returns a jQuery object to you, you can begin chaining and calling functions off those objects but to get a jQuery object you need to use the `jQuery` or `$` function.

You mentioned in a comment above your teacher had you do that to fix something. I imagine it was because jQuery was not initially included so he just created the `$` selector function to get you moving but I would hope he explained why he did that and how it can affect things later.

Comment: I understand now, thank you. That makes perfect sense.

Comment: Cool. Glad to help! Good luck.